# Twisted > How to read a TCP message longer than TCP frame-length e.g. 1380 bytes from a window TCP client

Tags: python, networking, tcp, twisted

I am writing a twisted server to read TCP messages up to 64KB. What I discovered was that mt datareciever was called by the linereciever class every 1380 bytes, which turned out to be the Windows client's TCP frame size. Is there a way to get around this without having to loop through these 1380 byte blocks?

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.enterprise.adbapi import ConnectionPool
class CSVReceiver(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, line):
        print 'line RX :', len(line) , ' : ' , str(line)
```

The dataReceived gets called and prints every 1380 bytes, e.g. 4X when a TCP message of 6KB is sent to our server. Any method to avoid this so we can process the entire string in one call-back?

Thank you.

STAN

Answer (score 1):

You asked this question on the python_forum, I answered you there. You want to be using LineReciever, and you want to set `MAX_LENGTH` to a higher number.

Comment: I tried MAX_LENGTH, no effect at all. When I send the same long TCP message from a Linux server using the same python script, the message was received OK.When sent from Windows, got chopped down to 1380 bytes, when sent from a cellular Linux box, got chopped down to 1358 bytes, coincides with the TCP frame or segment lengths of these two clients.

Comment: BTW, I started with linereceiver and encountered this problem. I need to qualify that the message received OK was sent from a script running local to the twisted server. Will try from another server ASAP.

Comment: Thanks!  This is absolutely correct.  Default value of MAX_LENGTH is 99,999 (100kb).  Override this as a class variable in your subclassing of Int32StringReceiver().

Answer (score 1):

TCP sends streams of data, not messages.  The intermediary network may break your streams up into arbitrarily small chunks for transport.  If you have control over the entire network where this is occurring, you can [tune your Windows clients](http://www.psc.edu/networking/projects/tcptune/OStune/winxp/winxp_stepbystep.html) to have a different window size.  But then you may also have to specially configure your local router to support [Jumbo frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame), since even Ethernet does not support frames of greater than 1500 octets by default.

Basically, for any network but the most trivial example, the answer to your question is "no".  But, why would you care about this?  The whole reason that [`LineReceiver`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver.html) exists is to deliver whole lines to you, rather than you having to worry about individual arbitrarily-sized chunks of data coming off a TCP stream.

Comment: Thanks. We actaully started off with LineReciever (and now testing with other methods) but LineReciever was trauncating off our messages to between 1350~1450 bytes (depending on client) but when we sent a message local to the server (e.g. to localhost), we received the entire message. Is the LineReciever designed to read and output and entire line instead of just TCP frames? Strangely, the MAX_LENGTH does not seem to have any effetc on the output of LineReceiver, weather if we set it to 100 or 10000 ...

Comment: You have to use `lineReceived` with LineReceiver, not `dataReceived`.