# What's the Optimal Approach to Sending Photos from a Client Upon Request Using Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm currently using the Twisted framework to establish a client-server communication system. The design involves multiple clients interacting with a single server. At any given time, the server might request a photo from any one of these clients. At present, I can successfully send a request from the server, have it received by the client, and get a response back. However, I'm encountering an issue where the photo file is being transmitted in chunks. Given that these chunks might be sent in an arbitrary manner, I'm unsure how to handle this. I'm seeking advice on how to implement this functionality, and also, I would like to know if using Twisted is an appropriate choice for my needs in the first place.

Client side:

```
class ClientProtocol(protocol.Protocol):

    def send_image(self):
        with open("image.jpg", "rb") as image_file:
            encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
            self.transport.write("SEND_IMAGE\n".encode())  # indicate that the following data is a photo response
            self.transport.write(encoded_image)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        message = data.decode() # decode from bytes to string
        print("Received response from server:", message)

        if message == "SEND_IMAGE":
            print("a request for SEND_IMAGE received")
            self.send_image()
```

Server side:

```
class ServerProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.waiting_for_photo = False

    def connectionMade(self):
        print("connection established")
        self.send_request() 

    def handle_image(self, encoded_image):
        print("attempt to receive a photo")
        decoded_image = base64.b64decode(encoded_image)
        with open("received_image.jpg", "wb") as image_file:
            image_file.write(decoded_image)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        message = data.decode()

        if message == "SEND_IMAGE":
            print("SEND_IMAGE reponse received")
            self.waiting_for_photo = True
        elif self.waiting_for_photo:
            print("trying to recieve photo")
            self.handle_image(data)
            self.waiting_for_photo = False  # reset the flag
```

Thanks

Comment: roughly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787547/twisted-how-to-read-a-tcp-message-longer-than-tcp-frame-length-e-g-1380-bytes I think

Comment: To give a reasonable answer to this question it would really help to know why making an HTTP server instead isn't the right answer here.